# Put value to a json response by using SBJson

Tags: ios, sbjson

I want to add value to a response. But the response is in this format

```
   {
  "participants": [
                    {
                      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0", 
                      "name": "alma" 
                     }
                  ],
  "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
  "_id": "52a80a5dccb8137326000027"
  }
```

How can I add values to the keys name & lat_long. I am using Sbjson method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your question clearly. Are you want to parse this Json into object Or any other?

Comment: What and where do you want to add ?

Comment: add some more information on your question

Comment: I want to pass value to key name & lat_long.But i don't know how to pass value.I have tried this code   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"a" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: give me your json link i will try and show you code....

Comment: Can't you get the key values and set the value for it ..

Comment: @KumarKl How can i get the key name?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"Give your URL Here"];

    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError * error;

    NSMutableDictionary * jsonDic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDic);


    NSMutableArray * jsonArray=jsonDic[@"participants"];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray);

    NSString * str =[jsonArray valueForKey:@"lat_long"];


    NSString *  str1 =[jsonArray valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you are asking about, but This helps you to get the keys of the Disctionary .

```
 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization .....//Parsed JSon
    NSMutableDictionary *arrCopy = [json mutableCopy];

   NSArray *keys= [json allKeys];
    for (NSString *keysV in keys){
        NSLog(@"Keys are %@", keysV);
        if ([keysV isEqualToString:@"_id"]) {
            [arrCopy setValue:@"121213211323" forKey:keysV];
        }else if (){

        }.......................
       }
    NSLog(@"After Value added: %@", arrCopy);
```

Comment: @KumarKl : Thanks...  But by using this code i got the key. I want to add value to the key by using PUT method.